# Is it possible to change a float (value) at a literal addresses?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

The code is inside of a .dll file that is injected inside of a game, then, when a certain command is typed on the injected .dll file, it changes an addresses value inside of the game to -2

I attempted to do it like this, since my friend told me this was how he did it, but I'm getting an error.

```
(float*)0x11FA6760 = -2
```

The error is "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" and I'm not sure what to do honestly

If this is not how you edit it, how do you?

Comment: Really?    You're asking for help on writing code to cheat in a game and (depending on what the hack does) to circumvent license restrictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
(float*)0x11FA6760 = -2;
```

is invalid since the LHS of the expression is not an lvalue.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
*(float*)0x11FA6760 = -2;
^^ Missing
```

Since you are using C++, you should use:

```
*(reinterpret_cast<float*>(0x11FA6760)) = -2;
```

Comment: Some more parenthesis would make it a little more cleare what is being dereferenced: `*((float*)0x11FA6760) = -2;`. Since you are using C++, you should use a C++ style typecast, though: `*(reinterpret_cast<float*>(0x11FA6760)) = -2;`